# How to remove the default fade transition between the native splash screen and the home screen in flutter? (Using native splash screen only)

Tags: flutter, splash-screen, flutter-animation

I have a native splash screen in flutter, but when the splash screen ends, it has a fade animation to my app home screen. I need to remove that, and still use the native splash. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found:

- Open your Android project inside your Flutter project
- In you Android project, go to `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`
- in that `AndroidManifest.xml` file, you should find one `activity` block
- in that block, comment or remove the two `meta-data` blocks, especially this one:

```xml
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
        android:resource="@drawable/launch-background" />
```

Not only the splash screen will still works, because you have `android:theme=@style/LaunchTheme` as attribute of the `MainActivity`, but il will also remove the glitch that you may have on your splash screen that shifts a little bit your logo (if you have one in your splash screen of course).

That solution works (at least for me) if you have a basic splash screen. I haven't tested that with a more advanced custom animated splash screen for example, so it might not be the perfect solution for everyone.

Comment: The commenting out <meta-data> block results in  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 and app crash for my app. Both release and debug.

Comment: @Dmytro That's strange, since that block is not a Resource. I double checked on my project and that `meta-data` is commented and I don't have any issue. Maybe your problem comes from elsewhere?

Comment: My app's Android builds are on stable latest channel - 1.22.6@Linux. For now I use recipe from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63156

Comment: I think I found - I had additional custom splash screen loader which tried to reuse the data from manifest. My apologies for disturbing.

Comment: @Dmytro No worries! Glad you found it ;)

Comment: @Dmytro could you explain your solution, if you've found it? I am using also this temporary method github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63156 (left an answer there) but it does not work

Comment: We have finished with https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63156#issuecomment-670390702 . iOS app wasn't a problem for customers (maybe it was smoother in release iOS builds already).